# Can anyone provide a working example for integration of MapTalks and Angular 9?

Tags: angular, maps

Tried to integrate **Maptalk** and **Angular**. But the map isn't getting rendered. It shows and empty space with the maptalks hyperlink at the left bottom. I tried searching for some tutorials but was unable to find any.

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as maptalks from 'maptalks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-new',
  templateUrl: './map-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-new.component.css']
})
export class MapNewComponent implements OnInit {
   map:any
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.map = new maptalks.Map('canvas', {
      center: [-0.113049,51.498568],
      zoom: 14
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="map-container">
    <div #canvas class="container"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width: 75%;
    height: 75vh;
}
```

Comment: you do need to add styling: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/maptalks/dist/maptalks.css">`. Probably add this in your `index.html` and see if it works

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqguso

Answer (score 1):

Few considerations.

On your html. Add 'id' to the div that the map would be rendered.

Add to your TS code:

Over declations add this:  @ViewChild('id_to_the_map') newMap: ElementRef;

And on AfterViewInit you should do it that way:

```
this.map = new maptalks.Map('id_to_the_map', {
    center: [126.9780, 37.5665],
    renderer: 'canvas',
    zoom: 5,
    baseLayer: new maptalks.TileLayer('base', {
        urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        repeatWorld: false, // remove if you want          
    })
});
```